# Alternative proof that $\dim L(V,W) = \dim V \cdot \dim W$ for $V,W$ finite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra

This question comes from Sterling Berberian's linear algebra text.

Suppose $V,W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces where $\dim V = n$, $\dim W = m$. Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be a basis of $V$ and $y_1,...,y_m$ be a basis of $W$.

Then define a linear mapping $E_{ij}$ such that $E_{ij}(x_i) = y_i$ and $E_{ij} = 0 $ for k not equal to j ( where $i \in {0,..m}$ and $j \in {0,...n}$

I wish to show that the $E_{ij}$ are independent and generating, which I am having difficult doing for both.

Suppose
$c_{1,1}E_{1,1} + ... + c_{n,m}E_{n,m} = 0$ for all $x \in V$. I am not sure how to proceed. Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $E_{ij}$ are linearly independent, assume that $\sum_{i,j} c_{ij} E_{ij} = 0$ (where $0$ here is the zero transformation). Evaluating both sides at $x_k$, we get

$$ \left( \sum_{ij} c_{ij} E_{ij} \right)(x_k) = \sum_{ij} c_{ij} E_{ij}(x_k) = \sum_{j} c_{kj} E_{kj}(x_k) = \sum_{k} c_{kj} y_j = 0_W. $$

Since the $(y_j)$ are linearly independent, we get $c_{kj} = 0$ for all $j$ and since $k$ was arbitrary, also for all $k$.

To show that $E_{ij}$ are generating, given a linear map $T \colon V \rightarrow W$ write $T(x_i) = \sum_{j} c_{ij} y_j$ and show that $T = \sum_{i,j} c_{ij} E_{ij}$ by evaluating both sides at $x_k$ and using the theorem that a linear map is determined uniquely on a basis.

Comment: I think for surjectivity that you only need to sum for one value of i and not for all of them, other than that this answer is great.